# Android IntentService not receiving extra

Tags: android, intentservice

I am starting the service , and I put a message in extra,

```
Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, TextToSpeechService.class);
mServiceIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "a message");
mServiceIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
this.startService(mServiceIntent);
```

but running , the service starts and the log shows a message = null...

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    static final String TAG = "MyService";

    public MyService() {
        super("My Service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "received message, should say: " + message);
    }
```

could it be related to the MIME TYPE, when I state mServiceIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
( using import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;)

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't tie up. You are using `Intent.Extra_TEXT` as the key for your extra - that is a constant value of `android.intent.extra.TEXT` but in your `Service` you try to retrieve the value of a key called "message". Also your `Intent` is an explicit one which is trying to start a `Service` called `TextToSpeechService` but the code you posted shows the `Service` is called `MyService`.

Comment: thanks a lot... I know about the class name .. I changed it in my post to MyService as a generic name ( but forgot this line..)  whatever I understand now the issue with the Extra.TEXT... you got the solution but how I can vote for it as an Answer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Squonk already mentioned your code doesn't really go together. To start your `Service` you have to use an `Intent` like this:

```
// The class you set here determines where the Intent will go.
// You want it to start MyService so we write MyService.class here.
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "a message");
startService(intent);
```

You can very well use the `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` constant as key for your extra, but you have to use the same key to retrieve the message in your `Service`:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    Log.d(TAG, "received message, should say: " + message);
}
```

The code in your `MyService` doesn't really show if you actually use the mime type in your `MyService` so I removed it from my example above.